# Link two dictionaries lists and calculate average values

Tags: python, list, join, mean

I am not used to code with Python, but I have to do this one with it. What I am trying to do, is something that would reproduce the result of SQL statment like this :

```
SELECT T2.item, AVG(T1.Value) AS MEAN FROM TABLE_DATA T1 INNER JOIN TABLE_ITEMS T2 ON T1.ptid = T2.ptid GROUP BY T2.item.
```

In Python, I have two lists of dictionnaries, with the common key 'ptid'. My dctData contains around 100 000 pdit and around 7000 for the dctItems. Using a comparator like `[i for i in dctData for j in dctItems if i['ptid'] == j['ptid']]` is endless:

```
ptid = 1
for line in lines[6:]: # Skipping header
    data = line.split()
    for d in data:
        dctData.append({'ptid' : ptid, 'Value': float(d)})
        ptid += 1 

dctData = [{'ptid':1,'Value': 0}, {'ptid':2,'Value': 2}, {'ptid':3,'Value': 2}, {'ptid':4,'Value': 5}, {'ptid':5,'Value': 3}, {'ptid':6,'Value': 2}]


for line in lines[1:]: # Skipping header
    data = line.split(';')
    dctItems.append({'ptid' : int(data[1]), 'item' : data[3]}) 

dctItems = [{'item':21, 'ptid':1}, {'item':21, 'ptid':2}, {'item':21, 'ptid':6}, {'item':22, 'ptid':2}, {'item':22, 'ptid':5}, {'item':23, 'ptid':4}]
```

Now, what I would like to get for result, is a third list that would present the average values according to each item in dctItems dictionnary, while the link between the two dictionnaries would be based on the 'pdit' value.

Where for example with the item 21, it would calculate the mean value of 1.3 by getting the values `(0, 2, 2)` of the ptid 1, 2 and 6:

And finally, the result would look something like this, where the key Value represents the mean calculated :

```
dctResults = [{'id':21, 'Value':1.3}, {'id':22, 'Value':2.5}, {'id':23, 'Value':5}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks you all for your help.

Comment: Where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Following up on jonrsharpe's comment, you're much more likely to get useful answers if you show what you've already tried.  Even if your code doesn't work, it will give people a useful starting point for helping you.

Comment: Are you stuck with this data format? If would be much easier to just use a single dictionary mapping items to lists of values.

Comment: Actually, the data comes from two different text files, so I can do pretty much what I want. The thing is I think I'm thinking to much like SQL, and I pretty much a beginner in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given those data structures that you use, this is not trivial, but it will become *much* easier if you use a single dictionary mapping items to their values, instead.

First, let's try to re-structure your data in that way:

```
values = {entry['ptid']: entry['Value'] for entry in dctData}
items = {}
for item in dctItems:
    items.setdefault(item['item'], []).append(values[item['ptid']])
```

Now, `items` has the form `{21: [0, 2, 2], 22: [2, 3], 23: [5]}`. Of course, it would be even better if you could create the dictionary in this form in the first place.

Now, we can pretty easily calculate the average for all those lists of values:

```
avg = lambda lst: float(sum(lst))/len(lst)
result = {item: avg(values) for item, values in items.items()}
```

This way, `result` is `{21: 1.3333333333333333, 22: 2.5, 23: 5.0}`

Or if you prefer your "list of dictionaries" style:

```
dctResult = [{'id': item, 'Value': avg(values)} for item, values in items.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you Tobias_k. I will modify the loading of the data file so that it has directly your variable values format. Could i do the same thing for the dctItems?

Comment: @orange If you organize your data as in my `items` dict, it holds the combined information from your `dctData` _and_ `dctItems` lists, i.e. you won't need the other any more.